# QBSDK Opening secondary instance of QuickBooks

Tags: vb.net, quickbooks, qbfc

I am developing a program in VS 2012, VB.NET.  I am using QBSDK v12.  I am attempting to open a connection to QB Enterprise 2012, but what happens is that it opens a secondary instance of QB, and then gives me an error message that it can't open two instances at once.  If I leave QB closed while trying to connect, I get a message that I need to give it permission first, which requires QB to be open when connecting.  I have tried to leave off the company file name, and only connect to the currently open session, but it still opens that secondary window.  I have updated QB to the latest and greatest.  Nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've seen this happen on my side is when I give a specific company file to open that is a different version that the QuickBooks that is currently running. For example, if the file is a QuickBooks 2012 Premier file, but you have QuickBooks 2012 Enterprise open, you'll get this problem.

Here's the code I typically use to connect when I want to open the file that is currently open in QuickBooks:

```
QBSessionManager SessionManager = null;
try
{
    SessionManager = new QBSesionManager();
    if(SessionManager == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Could not create SessionManager");
    SessionManager.OpenConnection2("AppID","CompanyName", ENConnectionType.ctLocalQBD);
    SessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);

    // DO MY QB STUFF

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if(SessionManager != null)
    {
        SessionManager.EndSession();
        SessionManager.CloseConnection();
        SessionManager = null;
    }
}
```